# I am trying to Upload the image using Django 1.8 and tastypie

Tags: tastypie, django-1.8

I am using Django 1.8 ,tastypie 0.13.0 versions,
while make the POST request it gives an error. UnsupportedFormat: The format indicated 'application/form-data' had no available deserialization method. Please check your `formats` and `content_types` on your Serializer.

```
class MultiPartResource(object):
    def deserialize(self, request, data, format=None):
    if not format:
        format = request.Meta.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json')
    if format == 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded':
        return request.POST
    if format.startswith('multipart/form-data'):
        data = request.POST.copy()
        data.update(request.FILES)
        return data
    return super(MultiPartResource, self).deserialize(request, data, format)

    def patch_detail(self, request, **kwargs):
        if request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', '').startswith('multipart/form-     data') and not hasattr(request, '_body'):
            request._body = ''
        return super(MultipartResource, self).patch_detail(request, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this issue: https://github.com/django-tastypie/django-tastypie/issues/42#issuecomment-5485666

It is about file upload support and how to deal with multipart/form-data.

Also, I suggest that you implement this tastypie field https://gist.github.com/klipstein/709890 to solve this.

Hope this work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [tastypie-extras](https://github.com/tomi77/django-tastypie-extras) `MultipartResourceMixin`

```
from tastypie_extras import MultipartResourceMixin

class MyResource(MultipartResourceMixin, ModelResource):
    ....
```

Tested on Django 1.4 and 1.8 and Tastypie 0.9.12 and 0.13.0